# Regex "does not contain" pattern issue for Natural Language Processing

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, pcre

Link to the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/arPqHq/4)

> I am implementing a simple NLP algo. I have already implemented the
> solution looping over the raw string to assist the regex, but now I
> want to see if I can do it in pure regex.

**I can't figure out how to get the 'build' group to respect the negative look ahead. I am trying to capture [*"Natural Language Processing" algorithms*]  Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks**

```
$subject_string = <<<'subject_string'
Projects I've built & Plan to build. HackMatch.io (May 2020 onward), 
As of October 2020, I intend to start implementing "Natural Language Processing" algorithms 
in PHP when I have time. I'll then use PHP to upload the results to big data tech (e.g. BigQuery) 
to create some data visualizations.
subject_string;

$pattern = <<<'pattern'
/\b(?'verb'build|make|implementing)
(?'build'.+?(?!build|make|implementing)) 
(?=\bin\b|\bon\b)
(?:build|make|implementing)??/ix
pattern;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject_string, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
/\b(?'verb'build|make|implementing)\s*
(?'build'(?:(?!(?&verb)).)*?) 
(?=\s*\b(?:in|on)\b)/ixs
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvD5U5/3). **Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?'verb'build|make|implementing)` - Group "verb": one of the words inside parentheses
- `\s*` - zer or more whitespaces
- `(?'build'(?:(?!(?&verb)).)*?)` - Group "build": any char, zero or more occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start any of the char sequences defined in the "verb" group
- `\s*` - zer or more whitespaces
- `(?=\b(?:in|on)\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a whole word `in` or `on`.